# Handling with multiple domains in Flask

Tags: python, routes, flask

I want to implement structure in Flask, which can handle multiple domains.
So when I type in browser "http://domain1.com/show/1", it actually executes function with routing like

```py
@app.route('<string:domain>/show/<int:id>')
def show(domain = '', id = ''):
    return 'Domain is ' + domain + ', ID is ' + str(id)
```

And it is very important, the URL in client's browser should be still "http://domain1.com/show/1". And as I know, when using `redirect` in Flask, it changes url. How should I organise such structure? Thanks!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The `request` object already has a [`url_root`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Request.url_root) parameter. Or you can use the `Host` header:

```
print request.url_root  # prints "http://domain1.com/"
print request.headers['Host']  # prints "domain1.com"
```

If you need to redirect within the application, `url_root` is the attribute to look at, as it'll include the full path for the WSGI application, even when rooted at a deeper path (e.g. starting at `http://domain1.com/path/to/flaskapp`).

It probably is better still to use [`request.url_for()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.url_for) to have Flask generate a URL for you; it'll take `url_root` into account. See the [URL Building](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#url-building) documentation.

Comment: By the way, what is the best decision to dynamically add SEO URLs, store them in database and add routes in my application? I think it may be easier and faster not to execute app.add_url_rule every time.

Comment: Find a pattern in them and register *one* route matching them all in one go?

Comment: I meant, they may be abolutely different and refers to different view functions, for example, /boots may refer to function show_category(id) and /timberland may refer to show_brand(id) the same time. So I need to store these connections in database, dynamically add/update/delete them. I see one decision, it is creating table with two columns, like 'keyword | refers_to', and for examples I have written fill it with data:
/boots        | /show_category(id = 1)
/timberland   | /show_brand(id = 1)

Comment: Then create function with route like '<string:keyword>', which finds this keyword in DB and redirects to refers_to. But this will change url in browser to `refers_to`, when I need to keep it `keyword`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what the code looks like with the import:

```
import flask

print flask.request.url_root  # prints "http://domain1.com/"
print flask.request.headers['Host']  # prints "domain1.com"
```